# How to simulate 10^5 sets of 51 tosses

Tags: r, loops, simulation

I want to write a loop to simulate 10^5 sets of 51 tosses in R.

The purpose of this loop is to know how many times we would expect the sequence of tosses to fluctuate if it was random.
I have tried many loops, but unfortunately couldn't do it, any help please? thank you.

Comment: What are the possibilities for a toss? What kind of fluctuation are you looking for? Please edit the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sample` and `replicate` functions to simulate your tosses (I assumed coin)

```
replicate(10^5, sample(c(0, 1), size = 51, replace = T))
```

This post can be useful to start with:

https://aosmith.rbind.io/2018/08/29/getting-started-simulating-data/

Comment: Please feel free to upvote and accept if this works for you